# Formulario con botón de suma y multiplicación no da resultado esperado

Tags: php, html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<h3><p> Recibir por el metodo get dos numeros</p></h3>
<h3><p> Y realizar resta, suma, multiplicacion y division</p></h3>
<form action="ejercicio2.php" method="get">
  
Numero 1: <input type="number" name="numero1"><br><br>
 
Numero 2: <input type="number" name="numero2"><br><br>

<input type="submit" name="multiplicar" value="multiplicar">

<input type="submit" name="sumar" value="sumar">

</form>
<?php

$numero1 = $_GET['numero1'];
$numero2 = $_GET['numero2'];
$btn_multiplicar = $_GET['multiplicar'];
$btn_sumar = $_GET['sumar'];
$resultado_multiplicacion = $numero1 * $numero2;
$resultado_suma           = $numero1 + $numero2;

if(isset($btn_multiplicar)){
   echo $resultado_multiplicacion;
}if(isset($btn_sumar)){
    echo $resultado_suma;
}else{
    echo "nada";
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

En este código estoy queriendo efectuar operaciones con un botón de suma y multiplicación y recibir los resultados de acuerdo al botón presionado pero me da un error de sintaxis ya le agregue el `isset` pero aun así me sale el error, no se si habrá otra forma de realizar este proceso

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imagino que el propósito del ejercicio es aprender el uso de [`if ... elseif ... else`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/control-structures.elseif.php) y el error de sintaxis es porque no usas bien esa estructura, tienes dos `if` seguidos y terminas con un `else`.

La sintaxis correcta en esos casos es:

```
if (expresion) {

} elseif (expresion) {

} else {

}
```

Así debería funcionar:

```
if(isset($btn_multiplicar)) {
   echo $resultado_multiplicacion;
} elseif (isset($btn_sumar)) {
    echo $resultado_suma;
} else {
    echo "nada";
}
```

Ahora bien, tu código queda expuesto a posibles casos de *`Undefined index`* y deberías usar una especie de variable final.

Quizá algo así es más coherente:

```
$outPut="Nada posteado";
if ( isset($_GET['numero1']) && isset($_GET['numero2']) ) {
    $numero1 = $_GET['numero1'];
    $numero2 = $_GET['numero2'];
    if ( isset($_GET['multiplicar']) ) {
        $outPut = $numero1 * $numero2;
    } elseif ( isset($_GET['sumar']) ) {
        $outPut = $numero1 + $numero2;
    } else {
        $outPut = "Ninguna operación posible";
    }
}
echo $outPut;
```

El código verifica primero que hay materia (los dos números fueron enviados) y luego decide la operación a realizar con esos números. Y, por otra parte, no declara variables que quizá no vayas a usar. Controla todo en una única variable de salida.

Cabe decir que en programas reales, estas verificaciones son más simples con el operador de fusión de null o con operadores ternarios, pero entiendo que lo tuyo es un ejercicio y no conviene pasarse de listo usando cosas que no hayas visto en clases.

Comment: Muchisimas gracias A. Cedano tu respuesta es lo que estaba buscando ahora comprendo mucho mejor como funciona PHP gracis por tu ayuda!!!